# Select tag with a lot of options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a little problem. I want to show select with users names as options.
Here my controller action:

```
def index
  @users = User.where.not(:id => current_user.id)
end
```

And view:

```
<%= select_tag :user_id, options_for_select(@users.map { |u| [u.full_name, u.id] }) %>
```

The problem is rails renders this view very slowly(especially on prod where a lot of users). How can I improve performance?

Comment: Are you doing anything else with the users?  If not then use pluck to return an array from the db so ruby doesn't have to make the array. `@users = User.where.not(:id => current_user.id).pluck(:full_name, :id)`  Assuming `full_name` is an attribute in the db, not a method.

Comment: @japed, unfortunately full_name is user's model method. It will be so easy:)

Comment: How many users have you got?

Comment: @RichPeck, about 7000 right now

Comment: If you have so many users that it's slowing your app down loading them all, then it seems like it would be bad design to show them all in a select tag:  a select tag with thousands of options is pretty horrible.  You should rethink what you're trying to achieve and approach it from a different direction.  You could have an ajax-driven autocomplete search box for example.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, there is a great sense in your words, I just selected wrong approach. I will rethink what I remake in my view. Thanks:)

Comment: Considering your purpose is to show a list of all users except the current one, why not maintain an array or hash of all users, and then simply remove the current_user at render time?

Comment: @jaxx, I guess my way is more correctly, because on my view I show already needed users and shouldn't write additional contidions. Sorry for my English:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I never understand why people don't use [`collection_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select):

```
<%= collection_select :user, :id, @users, :id, :full_name %>
```

---

I was just about to mention this when you replied to the comment....

*If you've got 7000 users, **don't** show them in a select tag*

Apart from the obvious problem of having to scroll through them, you'll have the other UI issue of the scroll area literally taking up the whole screen.

Select boxes are meant to offer a series of logical choices. The largest number of them I can think of would be country/state selections.

---

**Live Search**

If you're wanting to show so many users, you should start with your [`user story`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story).

This is where you basically approach the problem from the user's perspective. And as `Max` suggested, maybe a `live search` feature would be more appropriate, or at least a table:

```
#app/views/resources/_livesearch.html.erb
<%= text_field_tag :search, "Search", id: "user_search" %>

#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   get :search, on: :collection
end

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", "#user_search", function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: "users/search"
      data: { search: $(this).value() }
      success: function(data) {
         // show users
      }
   });
});

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def search
        @users = User.where("'name' LIKE ?", params[:search])
        render json: @users.to_json if request.xhr?
    end
end
```

You can see an example of this in action in one of the [demo apps](http://firststopcosmeticshop.herokuapp.com/) I made a while back:

[image]

---

**Pagination**

Alternatively, you could also use [*pagination*](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari) to create a table.

RailsCasts explains that one very well:

[image]

Comment: Why do you say `collection_select` is better than a simple `select_tag`? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: If you're using a collection, you don't have to bother with bullshit attribute mapping etc. It's just a simpler way to do it

Comment: I use select tag because I really don't know how show users. Using ajax and knocoutjs it works quicker. Thanks:)